# About definiteness of definition of algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I'm reading a note about the definition of algorithm, it has two requirements that I don't know what's the differences between them

> Definiteness: Every instruction should be **clear** and **unambiguous**. ([I found a source with exactly the same statement](https://www.cmpe.boun.edu.tr/~akin/cmpe223/chap1.htm))

From the resource I have there are 5 requirements: Input, Output, Definiteness, Finiteness, Effectiveness. I can understand the other 4 except the **Definiteness**. Can anyone provide some better definition if the above is not precise?

From the above I only suspect that there are at least two subtleties should be considered...

---

For conclusion from answers below: `definiteness = defined(clear) + only_one(unambiguous)`.

Comment: This is not really a definition in the proper matematical sense. It's a hand-wavy feel-good explanation that doesn't really explain anything. A proper definition can only rely on things that are already defined. We don't really know what words like "instruction" or "clear" or "unambiguous" mean, so they cannot be a part of the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't quite understand the definition of a term provided by some author, it's often helpful to look for other definitions of it. I especially like the one for "definite" from [wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definite):

> 2. Free from any doubt.

In this context, *clear* becomes *understandable*, and *unambiguous* becomes *with a single meaning*.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm should be clear and unambiguous. Each of its steps (or phases), and their inputs/outputs should be clear and must lead to only one meaning.

For example, if one step is to add two integers, we must define both “integers” as well as the “add” operation: we cannot for example use the same symbol to mean addition in one place and multiplication somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

If presented to an educated human, the text should allow him to simulate execution by hand in exactly the way you had in mind (same steps taken, same results obtained).

Comment: It seems like effectiveness is a consequence of definiteness...?

Comment: @ptr_user7813604: and conversely.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that instructions in an algorithm should have one and only one interpretation. Moreover, the interpretation should be obvious.

A statement like "Repeat steps 1 to 4 a few times" does not fit the criteria as "few times" can mean different number of tries to different people.

On the other hand, a statement like "Repeat steps 1 to 4 until **x** is equal to **y**" where **x** and **y** are some parameters in the algorithm is indeed clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Can I say that "clear" is for language that used to describing the algorithm, while "unambiguous" is about uniqueness of object, e.g. in your example x and y.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 Pretty much, yeah.